# Method won't work with a var - object

Tags: jquery

I have the following WORKING code snip:
`$(".container.menu > section > article").mCustomScrollbar("destroy");`

Now I started to save each element in a variable in jQuery. So I wrote the snip a bit different:

```
var containerMenu = $(".container.menu"),
    sectionMenu = containerMenu.children("section"),
    articleMenu = sectionMenu.children("article");

$(articleMenu).mCustomScrollbar("destroy");
```

But when I write it like this, it won't work.

Then I tried again something different:

```
var articleMenu = $(".container.menu > section > article");

articleMenu.mCustomScrollbar("destroy");
```

But also this won't work.
At last, I tried to surround the *articleMenu* with the jQuery brackets:
`$(articleMenu).mCu...`

But this also won't work.

So why this won't work? I don't want to always write the whole jQuery selector, just call the variable.

---

Edit:

```
var container = $(".container"),
    section = container.children("section"),
    article = section.children("article"),

    menuTrigger = container.children(".menu-trigger"),

    containerMenu = $(".container.menu"),
    sectionMenu = containerMenu.children("section"),
    articleMenu = $(".container.menu > section > article");


function triggerMenu(){

   container.toggleClass("menu");

   if(container.hasClass("menu")){
      // won't work
      articleMenu.mCustomScrollbar("destroy");

      // will work
      $(".container.menu > section > article").mCustomScrollbar("destroy");
   }

}
```

this version won't work. When I replace the `articleMenu` it works.

*Edit2*:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <title>index</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" />
        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="menu-trigger">menu</a>
            <section>
                <article class="about active">
                    <h1>about</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></p>
                </article>
                <article class="design">
                    <h1>design</h1>
                    <p>this is an article</p>
                    <p>have fun with it</p>
                </article>
                <article class="photography">
                    <h1>photography</h1>
                    <p>this is an article</p>
                    <p>have fun with it</p>
                </article>
            </section>
        </div>

    <!-- Additional javascript plugins -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function($){
            $(window).load(function(){
                $("article").mCustomScrollbar({
                    contentTouchScroll: true,
                    mouseWheelPixels: 300,
                    autoHideScrollbar: true,
                    scrollButtons:{
                        enable: true,
                        scrollType: "continuous",
                        scrollSpeed: 300
                    },
                    advanced:{
                        autoScrollOnFocus: true
                    }
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    var container = $(".container"),
        section = container.children("section"),
        article = section.children("article"),

        menuTrigger = container.children(".menu-trigger"),

        containerMenu = $(".container.menu"),
        sectionMenu = containerMenu.children("section"),
        articleMenu = $(".container.menu > section > article");


    function triggerMenu(){

        container.toggleClass("menu");

        if(container.hasClass("menu")){
            // articleMenu.mCustomScrollbar("destroy");
            $(".container.menu > section > article").mCustomScrollbar("destroy");
        }

    }


    function init(){

        menuTrigger.on("click", triggerMenu);

    }


    init();

 })();
```

Comment: Just after defining your variables, console.log each of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why these two should be any different:

```
// 1
var articleMenu = $(".container.menu > section > article");
articleMenu.mCustomScrollbar("destroy");

// 2
$(".container.menu > section > article").mCustomScrollbar("destroy");
```

The fact that you say they are, leads me to expect that you moved your jQuery selector code to a different spot (which makes sense). However, it seems you moved it to a spot in your code that is called when the element does not exist. So jQuery can't find the element, and this 'result' is stored in your variable. In which case, the way you're selecting the element isn't the problem, it's just where (or rather when) you are trying to select it.

If you can't figure out if the above is true by yourself, please post the whole piece of code so we can see what happens.

**Edit:**

Indeed it seems to be a timing problem. You declare articleMenu at code runtime, but the element probably doesn't exist yet. If you change to the following, it should work:

> function triggerMenu(){
>
> ```
>    // Once we're inside the function, the element should exist 
>    var articleMenu = $(".container.menu > section > article"); 
>
>    container.toggleClass("menu");
>
>    if(container.hasClass("menu")){
>       // should work now
>       articleMenu.mCustomScrollbar("destroy");
>    }
> ```
>
> }

If the element exists on the page from the beginning, another solution might be wrapping your code in the following statement:

> $(document).ready(function () {
>
> ```
>    // Your code here will be executed when the page has finished loading
> ```
>
> });

Comment: Hey Hans. Sorry for my late respond. Was busy this week. Please take a look to my Edit, I posted the whole code.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. But it's strange. I tried both of your solution, but both won't work! I really don't understand what's going on...

Comment: Can you post your full code after applying solution one? In theory it's not possible that the element doesn't exist at the start of the triggerMenu function, but it does work 3 lines below, because the DOM hasn't had a chance to change in the meantime. Something fishy is indeed going on.

Comment: No I posted the whole HTML File and all custom javascript lines

Comment: I see your selectors contain ".container.menu", but there is no element with those classes. Just one with 'container'. Can you change the affected selectors and see if that helps?